# Angular2 fails work in Asp.net

Tags: asp.net, angular

I have bundled all the angular app through angular cli.  It works perfectly fine when I run it on iis. However, when I use those script and embedding in ASP.net it fails with below error.

```
bootstrap 3203799…:52 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'call' of undefined
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap 3203799…:52)
    at Object.91 (src async:7)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap 3203799…:52)
    at Object.214 (main.bundle.js:158)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap 3203799…:52)
    at webpackJsonpCallback (bootstrap 3203799…:23)
    at main.bundle.js:1
```

here is my asp.net page

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Home Page - test1</title>    
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/site.css" />        
</head>
<body>
  
    <div class="container body-content">
        <app-root>Loading...</app-root>            
        <footer>
            <p>&copy; 2017 - test1</p>
        </footer>
    </div>
    
        <script src="/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
        <script src="/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
        <script src="/js/site.js?v=EWaMeWsJBYWmL2g_KkgXZQ5nPe-a3Ichp0LEgzXczKo"></script>
        <script src="/js/inline.bundle.js"></script>
        <script src="/js/main.bundle.js"></script>
        <script src="/js/polyfills.bundle.js"></script>
        <script src="/js/styles.bundle.js"></script>
        <script src="/js/vendor.bundle.js"></script>
    

<!-- Visual Studio Browser Link -->
<script type="application/json" id="__browserLink_initializationData">
    {"requestId":"eb15d059015940b7baff2cceaf31df3e","requestMappingFromServer":false}
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost:31560/78a50a5003884c18a14360745dbcb5bc/browserLink" async="async"></script>
<!-- End Browser Link -->

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: which one is the angularjs file in the js scripts section?

Comment: Here is the files.         <script src="/js/inline.bundle.js"></script>
        <script src="/js/main.bundle.js"></script>
        <script src="/js/polyfills.bundle.js"></script>
        <script src="/js/styles.bundle.js"></script>
        <script src="/js/vendor.bundle.js"></script>

Comment: I would expect `main.bundle.js` to come last

Comment: You are the champ. Thanks, bro.